# ELU, Stack Overflow, and chat vandalized by Martians

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Here is a screenshot of English SE newest questions tab. Look at the red gibberish (likely Martian handwriting).

[image]

Here is the text:

> tdber 18 Tvrptvinp-oldpanigno"viTclzinsti

> tdber 18 Tvrptvinp-
>
> oldpanigno"viAddzinsti butt
>
> /bvalui Addzon-td

I refreshed the page and the red text vanished.

**This is no photoshop!** It occurred not five minutes ago. I'm not sure how to tag this besides [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

---

## EDIT

Here’s a copy of it happening on StackOverflow, too, running Safari under Darwin:

[image: StackOverflow screwed-up image]

and here again:

[image: SO delete tab garbling]

When in this state, `View Source` brings up a totally whited-out page.  If you try to grab the garbled text with the mouse, it is correct when you paste it into a non-Safari window.

Also, chat is screwed up, in a limited fashion:

[image: chat garbled imaged]

Comment: I’ve seen this, too.  Restarting Safari always makes it go away.

Comment: I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Both Safari and Chrome are Webkit browsers.

Comment: It never happens in Opera.  It also happens on SO, but only under Safari.

Comment: @tchrist: Don't feel so smug. Other horrible things do happen in Opera.

Comment: @Robusto “Smug” doesn’t enter into providing a datapoint.

Comment: If it's really Martians, they must've come from Area 51.

Comment: @tchrist: Shut up or I'll wake up Smaug.

Comment: I think this should be on MSO. It's not site specific: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6226474#6226474

Comment: This got [norepro]ed on ELU, but now that we have additional screenshots from SO and chat, I'm migrating it to MSO.

Answer (score 1):

We can't reproduce this.

My gut is saying "dodgy proxy" or "ISP trying (and failing) to injecting ads", but that's just a hunch.  If you can capture the traffic when this happens we'll take another look, but with nothing else to go on I'm [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)'ing it.

Comment: What do you mean by "capture the traffic"?

Comment: @Luke - fiddler, network tab in Chrome or Firefox, anything where we can see the actual HTTP going back and forth.  Basically we need to see when and where (ie. what request to the server) that garbage is getting added.

Comment: I’ve saved off the HTML from the screens shown above, and there is no garbage in the HTML, just as there is none when you use the mouse to grab it.  It is only in the display.